# Webpack bundle when importing functions from a file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some confusion regarding how Webpack creates the output bundle. Let's say I have a statement like this in my code:

```
import { func1 } from 'library1'
```

In this case, will the entire `library1` be included in the bundle or only `func1`? What if `func1` is dependent on another function `func2` inside `library1`?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, `func2` has to be defined/imported(Just like the way you mentioned in your question) in the `library1` file of yours.

Once all the dependencies are resolved (means, you import or define all the essential functions for your code to work properly), you will see all the functions (`func1` and `func2`) in your bundle file.